# Unix: Print file name and line number of each line that exceeds 80 characters of each file in a folder

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Title sums it up. I'm working in Unix, korn shell. And I'm trying to print the file name and line number of each line that exceeds 80 characters of each file in the current folder.

I can use "**awk 'length > 80' *.cpp**" to give all lines longer than 80 characters, but I can't seem to pull out the line numbers or file names. I tried to use cat as well, because it allows for line numbers.

The idea is to get output similar to this:

```
test.cpp line 36
    std::cout << ... line that is over 80 characters

test2.cpp line 40
    Another line that is over 80 characters
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Almost there! This will give you a `grep`-style output, useful in editors like Vim to be able to navigate the output:

```
awk 'length > 80 {print FILENAME "(" FNR "): " $0}' *.cpp
```

Or to give the format you asked for:

```
awk 'length > 80 {print FILENAME " line " FNR "\n\t" $0}' *.cpp
```

`FILENAME` and `FNR` (like `NR`, but for that particular file) are special variables in `awk`.

Or you could use `grep` itself, of course:

```
grep -n '^.\{80\}' *.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost perfect; is there some way to get the line numbers right? I think the printed line number corresponds to the combined text of all the files together and not the individual file itself.

Comment: @Carlin: interesting. I suggest using `grep`.

Comment: @Carlin: I've fixed the `awk` solutions now, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'length > 80 { print FILENAME ":" NR ": " $0 }' *.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost perfect; is there some way to get the line numbers right? I think the printed line number corresponds to the combined text of all the files together and not the individual file itself.

Comment: @Carlin: Yes. Use `FNR` instead of `NR` as in my answer.